# Using where in salesforce query

Tags: casting, salesforce, where-clause

I currently have this statment:

```
$query = 'SELECT DataStream__c from JUS_Contract__c limit 50';
```

Which works fine, but I want to only select the datastream when Datavalue = 3;

for example:

```
$query = 'SELECT DataStream__c from JUS_Contract__c where DataValue__c=3 limit 50';
```

When this is atempted I get a notice saying:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

I know this is because DataValue returns something like this:

```
stdClass Object ( [Id] => [DataValue__c] => 3)
```

When I do:

```
 $query = 'SELECT DataStream__c from JUS_Contract__c limit 50';
      $response = $mySforceConnection->query(($query));
      //print_r($response->records);
      foreach ($response->records as $record) {
       print_r($record);
```

(for printing I fixed it by doing this: `echo $record->DataStream__c;` )

However I can not do that in the query, and am unsure how to change it to either a string or a int inside the query so that I can use the where command on it. Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Are you sure the api label for the field is `DataValue__c`?

Comment: Yes, and if I just do SELECT DataValue__c from JUS_Contract__c I can get its value, looks like stdClass Object ( [Id] => [DataValue__c] => 3)

Comment: I don't know what `stdClass Object ( [Id] => [DataValue__c] => 3)` is but if you query out all of the records and then you can qualify what you need in your `foreach` loop, also this may be better if you ever need to query out of the `JUS_Contract` again

Comment: @EricSSH Very unsure what you mean. When I query it returns that stdClass Object line. Meaning I can not simply compare to see if it = 3, because it does not =3, it equals that whole object. Making my where statement not work. Hence this whole question.